# overwriting NVDATA EEDPT tag mode setting

Tags: boot

I get this message when booting `overwriting NVDATA EEDPT tag mode setting`

Is this a bad thing?

Running UBUNTU 20.04LTS on a Dell precision tower 7910 Workstation

```
Apr 10  5:18:58 PM systemd: Failed to start VTE child process 8933 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 8876.
Apr 10  5:03:44 PM kernel: sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg] Assuming drive cache: write through
Apr 10  4:18:53 PM kernel: usb 5-1.1: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84
Apr 10  4:18:45 PM kernel: 
Apr 10  4:18:45 PM kernel: usb 5-1.1: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84
Apr 10  4:18:44 PM kernel: mpt3sas_cm0: overriding NVDATA EEDPTagMode setting
```

I think the message refers to the first item `failed to start vte child process 8933 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 8876`

Thank you for the help

Comment: It says "overriding" not "overwriting". There is a sizable difference, so don't be too concerned. Furthermore, this is merely informative and nothing to be concerned about.

Comment: Thank You Erich for your quick response